# Installing a package which depends on Entity Framework via NuGet

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

Okay, so I have an internal library for entities, and I have a web application which depends on the library.

So the dependency looks like this:

- Web Application

  - Library

    - Entity Framework

The library is managed via an internal NuGet feed.

The problem I have is that every time I update the library within the web application, the `install.ps1` script gets run for Entity Framework. This creates an EF folder (along with with `Model1.tt`, `Model1.cs`, `Model1.Context.tt`, `Model1.Context.cs` files) within the web application.

I don't want this obviously, so every time I update the library project, I have to delete files from the web application.

I feel there's something I'm missing here - how do I get to use Entity Framework as a dependency without it creating the `EF` folder every time I update the library project within the web application?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I never really had the time to look into it properly. Would love to hear of a solution if you find something though!